# Need help getting category where more than one article

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to develop a knowledge base system in PHP. I am trying to just return the categories where there are 1 or more posts. I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT `category_id`, `category_name` FROM `categories` WHERE(SELECT 
`category_id` FROM `posts` HAVING COUNT(`posts`.`post_id`) >= 1) ORDER BY 
`category_id` ASC
```

I try it and I get all the categories and not just the ones with more than 1 post in them. I'm not sure what the problem is. Please help

Comment: where does php come into light?

Comment: you tagged as [php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) but no code to support the question. Nor do we know which MySQL API you're using to connect with. Edit: someone removed the php tag.

Comment: change '>=1' to '>1'

Comment: Also need your SQL error or output that isn't correct.

Comment: Your first sentence says "1 or more posts". The third sentence says "more than 1 post". Which do you actually want?

Comment: The title says *more than one*, so it's 2:1 for `>1` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **1 or more post**, you just need a simple `INNER JOIN` between `categories` and `posts`. This will only return rows where the `category_id` exists in both tables, which means there's at least 1 post for the category.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.category_id, c.category_name
FROM categories AS c
JOIN posts AS p ON c.category_id = p.category_id
```

If you actually want categories where there's **more than 1 post**, you can use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.category_name
FROM categories AS c
JOIN posts AS p ON c.category_id = p.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

#1: `>1` instead of `>=1`

#2: You count all posts, not the posts per category. Either switch to a Correlated Subquery or better:

```
SELECT `category_id`, `category_name` 
FROM `categories` AS c 
JOIN 
 ( SELECT `category_id` 
   FROM `posts`
   GROUP BY category_id 
   HAVING COUNT(`posts`.`post_id`) > 1
) AS p
ON c.category_id = p.category_id 
ORDER BY `category_id` ASC
```

Comment: dnoeth nailed it. This will solve your issue. You might also consider only returning distinct category_ids from your sub-query.

Comment: @BrandonBlack: `GROUP BY` always returns distinct values, no need to add that.

Comment: The question says "1 or more posts". This answer is for "more than 1 post", which is not the same thing.

Comment: @Barmar: Correct, so the query is simplified to a simple JOIN. But then it reads *the ones with more than 1 post* :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing which column to use in the where statement:

```
SELECT `category_id`, `category_name` FROM `categories` WHERE category_id in 
(SELECT `category_id` FROM `posts` HAVING COUNT(`posts`.`post_id`) >= 1) 
ORDER BY `category_id` ASC
```